# Creating a box by clicking and dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create a box I can resize by clicking and dragging. I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/A2fr4/2/ - that's close, but not there. In this jsfiddle I can press down the mouse button to create the box and then I can come back and resize that box.  What I really want is to be able to click and drag in one motion an have the box expand out to follow the cursor position, exactly what I have except I don't want to have to come back after the first click and click it again the start the resize.

Can someone see what I'm missing?

Thanks

```
$('<div>')
        .resizable(groupBox_resizeOps)
        .css({'border'      : '1px dotted black',
                'left'      : groupBox_x0,   
                'top'           : groupBox_y0,
                'position'  : 'absolute',
                'width':'0px',
                'height':'0px'
             })
        .addClass('groupBox')
        .appendTo('#canvas')
        ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the last added element to adjust the width and height by yourself. JQueryUI resizable have no available methods / events to do this yet.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BpKhj/)

```
// Additional variables
var lastAddedElement;
var groupBox_x0;
var groupBox_y0;
$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e) {

            /*
               Create a resizable group box 
            */

            console.log("document mousedown: e.target is ", e.target.id, "Starting a group box");
            groupBox_x0 = e.pageX;      
            groupBox_y0 = e.pageY;
            lastAddedElement = $('<div>')
                    .resizable(groupBox_resizeOps)
                    .css({'border'      : '1px dotted black',
                          'left'        : groupBox_x0,   
                          'top'         : groupBox_y0,
                          'position'    : 'absolute',
                          'width':'0px',
                          'height':'0px'
                         })
                    .addClass('groupBox')
                    .appendTo('#canvas')
                    ;            
}).mousemove(function(e){
    // Set the width and height to the last added element.
    if (lastAddedElement != null) {
        groupBox_x1 = e.pageX;
        groupBox_y1 = e.pageY;
        lastAddedElement.css({'width': groupBox_x1 - groupBox_x0,
                              'height': groupBox_y1 - groupBox_y0});
    }
}).mouseup(function(e){
    // Clear the variable
    lastAddedElement = null;
});
```